# How to find the inventory of all images and packages available in Nexus?

Tags: nexus, sonatype

Is there any API or report to query and find all available versions in nexus for Docker, maven etc ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Nexus API to query/search, find an item in nexus.
The API url is like: `Your_nexus_ur/swagger-ui/`

[image]